# Why do I need to pass an anonymous function into the onClick event?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I've been trying to learn the basics of React. However, I've come across a section in the tutorial that asks me to place an `alert()` inside of an onClick event as such:

```
        <button className="square" onClick={() => {alert("click");}}>
            {this.state.value}
        </button>
```

I don't understand why the arrow function is required - why can't I just have the alert() on its own?

The docs state:

> Forgetting () => and writing onClick={alert('click')} is a common mistake, and would fire the alert every time the component re-renders.

Which is correct - I've tried this, and it does continually call `alert()`. But why? Isn't it supposed to fire onClick, and not on render? What does the anonymous function do that stops this behaviour?

Comment: Because you're passing a function to be called, instead of calling the function and passing the result. `{alert("click")}` is invoking the function, like `{(() => alert("click"))()}`.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Because if you call a function, then the function runs. (And you get the return value from it)

```js
const onClick = alert("hello");
console.log(onClick);
```

If you *define a function* (X) that calls a function (Y), then it doesn't call Y until you call X.

```js
const onClick = () => alert("hello");
console.log(onClick);
```

Answer (score 5):

Basically there is differences between calling (Invoking) a function `alert()` and Defining (Expressing) a function `() => {alert()}`

When the code runs, i.e when react renders the component, any function call would run that function and that's why we can use [IIFE](http://benalman.com/news/2010/11/immediately-invoked-function-expression/) `(function() { } )()` to inject functions to window object at runtime.

However, handling events with inline function call (like `onclick={()=>{alert()}}`) is not recommended because every time that event triggered, a new instance of that function would be created and it may slow down your app,

Instead you can DEFINE a function for handling events and just call it when that specific event triggered:

```
// Bad
render() {
  return <button onclick={() => {this.setState({btnClicked: true})}}> Click! </button>
}

// Good
render() {

  const handleClick = () => {
    this.setState({btnClicked: true})
  }

  return <button onclick={handleClick}> Click! </button>
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Because you need a *function* that gets called only in the instant that the button is clicked. If you pass `alert('click')` then the parser will find a *function call* and execute it instantly when it is going over that file.