# Callback function on button onClick in React Functional Component

Tags: reactjs, react-native, jsx

I have two examples of calling onRemove method on button click in jsx . However although there is no compilation error , the example 2 doesnt render anything on screen which means basically it is wrong.

What is wrong with the example 2 and why do we need to pass another anonymous function and instead not just call {onRemove(item.id)} on button click?

**eg1:**

```
function onRemove(id) {
    //
    }
    
    <button type="button" onClick={() => onRemove(item.id)}>
```

**eg2:**

```
    function onRemove(id) {
    //
    }
    
    <button type="button" onClick={onRemove(item.id)}>
```

**Edit**:
Similarly onChange works like eg2 above.

```
const handleChange = (search) => {
    //
  }; 
<input
        id="search"
        type="text"
        onChange={handleChange}/>
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why do I need to pass an anonymous function into the onClick event?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57392633/why-do-i-need-to-pass-an-anonymous-function-into-the-onclick-event)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, it's true that in your case the second example is incorrect. I was also taken aback the first time I encountered this, as I was expecting it to behave like it would in HTML...

```
<button onclick="myFunction()"></button>
```

... but JSX does not work like that. That's because, unlike HTML where `onclick`'s value is executed as normal JavaScript, in JSX it is passed along as a callback function. Keep in mind that JSX is not HTML, but rather XML syntax that is transpiled back into JS in the build process.

```
function Component(props) {
  return <button type="button" onClick={() => onRemove(item.id)}/>
}
```

would be transpiled to

```
function Component(props) {
  return React.createElement('button', {onClick: () => onRemove(item.id), type: 'button'}, null);
}
```

I think you can now see why it would be necessary to wrap the function call into an anonymous function, as it would instead pass along not the function, but whatever the function would return. That is useful when you actually want to do that, such as in this case:

```
function Component(props) {
  return <div>{myFunction()}</div>
}
```

so that's why the second example wouldn't work. If you would like to get deeper into this, I suggest you read [this](https://reactjs.org/docs/introducing-jsx.html) and [this](https://reactjs.org/docs/jsx-in-depth.html).

Comment: Then how is onChange working without wrapping an anonymous function as shown in the question?

Comment: @user1907849 in that case, you are not calling the function (in JavaScript, a function is called by using the "()" notation after the function name), so that's why it works. It is instead passing the function reference. Of course the drawback in this case is that the click event would just call the function without any parameters.