# react bootstrap onClick button

Tags: reactjs, onclick, react-bootstrap

created an `Offcanvas` component and inside it a `Button` having `onClick` event handler. the problem is whenever the component is loaded the `onClick` fires automatically. I don't have any idea why this happens so tried to find any instruction here.
my code:

```
      <Offcanvas show={canvas} onHide={handleClose} scroll="true" style={{fontSize: 12}}>
        <Offcanvas.Header closeButton>
          <Offcanvas.Title>
            <Row className="py-3">
              <Col>
                <h5>Order entries</h5>
              </Col>
              <Col>
                <Button variant="danger" onClick={alert('hello')}>Reset</Button>
              </Col>
            </Row>
          </Offcanvas.Title>

        </Offcanvas.Header>
        <Offcanvas.Body>
          <Entries />
        </Offcanvas.Body>
      </Offcanvas>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try changing `onClick={alert('hello')` to `onClick={() => alert('hello')`

[Here's a good explanation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57392633/why-do-i-need-to-pass-an-anonymous-function-into-the-onclick-event#:%7E:text=Because%20you%20need%20a%20function,is%20going%20over%20that%20file.)

Answer (score 3):

Just use a function inside event attributes to prevent the problem, like this:

```
<Button onClick={() => alert('hello')}>Reset</Button>
```